# JTable RowSorter after performing operations with values of cells

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, rowsorter

I have cells with which I have to perform some operations before sorting the rows. For Example: If a string is given, I convert it to the sum of its ASCII values. And then I want to sort the JTable as per the sums of the ASCII values. The code below is for sorting alphabetically. But I do not want that.

```
    DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter) jTable1.getRowSorter());
    ArrayList list_ar = new ArrayList();
    list_ar.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(2, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    sorter.setSortKeys(list_ar);
    sorter.sort();
```

I tried experimenting and manipulating the arraylist (`list_ar`) but the Arraylist when converted into Object array, gives addresses as its elements. Please recommend me a proper way of performing such operations.

Comment: Have you tried a custom `Comparator`?

Answer (score 0):

> The code below is for sorting alphabetically. But I do not want that.

Don't store a String in the TableModel.

Instead store an `Integer` value. You will also need to override the `getColumnClass()` method of the TableModel to return `Integer.class` for that column. Then the JTable will use the appropriate Comparator to sort the integer values.